# Hazelcast custom log file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast IMDG (v3.8.2).

Is it possible to change the log file Hazelcast writes to? Currently all the Hazelcast logs are written to my catalina.out, but I want to write them to some other file - let's say "hazelcast.log".

Couldn't really figure out how to do it from the documentation - it only mentions changing the logger type & level:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.2/manual/html-single/index.html#logging-configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.0/manual/html/ch13s11.html

Hazelcast supports multiple logging frameworks from which you're able to pick one.

- jdk:JDK logging (default)
- log4j:Log4j
- slf4j:Slf4j
- none:disable logging

E.g. if you would go for log4j then you need to configure a properties file that routes all Hazelcast logging to the desired file.

**Hazelcast configuration xml**

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-2.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j</property>
    </properties>
    ...
</hazelcast>
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <!-- TODO: define the file appender -->
    ...
    <logger name="com.hazelcast" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="myfileappender"/>
    </logger>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing piece :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `hazelcast.logging.type` of `slf4j`, then you can dovetail in with the logger for the web container, or for the jar file

Don't use `log4j` directly or indirectly if at all possible. That means Log4j ONE which is a dead project.

If you use `slf4j`, you can use Log4j TWO or various other loggers, whichever suits you.

Log4j ONE - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/
Log4j TWO - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/